# Ordering on $\lambda$-tabloids

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

Let $\lambda$ be a partition of $n$ ($n=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots + \lambda_k$ and $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge\cdots$).

There is an ordering on the collection of all the $\lambda$-tabloids:

Let $\{t_1\}$ and $\{t_2\}$ be two $\lambda$-tabloids. We sat $\{t_1\}<\{t_2\}$ if there is an $i$ such that

- $i$ is in higher row of $\{t_1\}$ than $\{t_2\}$
- for all $j>i$, the entry $j$ lies in same row of $\{t_1\}$ and $\{t_2\}$.

> **Q.0** Is there any other equivalent version of this ordering? (I didn't get what we want to say through this ordering?)
>
> **Q.1** For what purpose this ordering of tabloids is important in the representations of symmetric groups?
>
> **Q.2** Since $\lambda$-tabloids are canonically in bijection with subgroups of $S_n$ of the form $S_{\lambda_1}\times S_{\lambda_2}\times \cdots \times S_{\lambda_k}$, so on the {\it subgroup level}, what the above ordering corresponds? What the about ordering says in terms of subgroups?

Comment: **Q.2**: No, $\lambda$-tabloids are not in bijection with such subgroups. $S_{\{1,2\}} \times S_{\{3,4\}}$ would correspond under your "bijection" to two different tabloids: one whose first row is $\{1,2\}$ and whose second row is $\{3,4\}$, and another where the rows are switched. So you don't get an ordering on Young subgroups.

Comment: **Q.1**: Orderings like this (there are several others) are commonly used for induction arguments: You prove something about a tabloid, assuming (as induction hypothesis) that it already is proven for all smaller tabloids (smaller with respect to this ordering).

Comment: **Q.0**: You can encode each $\lambda$-tabloid as an $n$-tuple $\left(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n\right)$ of positive integers, where each $i_k$ is the number of the row that contains $k$. Then, the ordering corresponds to the reverse-lexicographic order on these $n$-tuples (i.e., lexicographic order if you turn the tuples around).